# Overwriting jQuery Global Objevt Variable WIthin Dynamic Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Within a global object there are settings that should change based on certain user input.  For example, if you check "no" for div 1, not only will div-one be hidden, the variable's value will be updated to 0.

The issue is that the function that hides the divs is dynamic, and uses data- to help find the proper div to hide.  I am having trouble overwriting the proper global variable.

I have tried things such as adding mark up to help target the specific variable, but it has not worked properly.

HTML

```
<p>Div 1</p>
<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-one" type="radio" name="enableDivOne" value="yes" checked><span>Yes</span>

<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-one" type="radio" name="enableDivOne" value="no">
<span>No</span>

<p>Div 2</p>
<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-two" type="radio" name="enableDivTwo" value="yes" checked><span>Yes</span>

<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-two" type="radio" name="enableDivTwo" value="no">
<span>No</span>

<div class="div-one">One</div>

<div class="div-two">Two</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var settings = {

    enableDivOne: 1, // overwrite this when div 1 option is changed
    enableDivTwo: 1 // overwrite this when div 2 option is changed

};

$('.toggle').change(function () {
    var target = $(this).data("target"),
        element = $(this),
        name = element.val(),
        is_checked = element.prop('checked'),
        setting = $(this).data("setting");

    if  (name == 'yes') {
        $(target).slideDown(300);
        console.log(settings.enableDivOne);
        console.log(settings.enableDivTwo);
    } else {
        $(target).slideUp(300);
        console.log(settings.enableDivOne);
        console.log(settings.enableDivTwo);
    }
});
```

To summarize, I am trying to figure out a dynamic way to change certain variables.

[Fiddle to example so far](http://jsfiddle.net/qjeg34nx/2/)

Comment: Did you know that you can reference properties with bracket syntax? You could do `settings[name] = 0`, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this

```
    var settings = {

    enableDivOne: 1,
    enableDivTwo: 1

};

$('input:radio.toggle').change(function(e) {
    var target = $('#div-' + $(this).data("target")),
        value = $(this).val();
    settings[$(this).prop('name')] = value;

    target.slideToggle(300);
    console.log("div one :" + settings.enableDivOne);
    console.log("div two :" + settings.enableDivTwo);
});
```

I change your target mark up from

```
data-target=".div-one"
```

to

```
data-target="one"
```

as personal preference; it feels more semantic

you can test it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/v43hy5ye/

Comment: Yes, I agree - it definitely feels cleaner and more semantic, great tip.  Out of curiousity, how would this change if the the settings object had another one inside, such as divSettings - see here: https://jsfiddle.net/v43hy5ye/1/

Comment: you would just shift one level down on the object tree changing `settings[$(this).prop('name')]` to `settings.divSettings[$(this).prop('name')]`

Comment: Is it possible to make the .divSettings part dynamic - maybe if it was in the HTML somewhere etc.?

Comment: sure you can use any attribute of the DOM like the id  eg `settings[target.prop('id')][$(this).prop('name')]`

Comment: This might explain what I mean better https://jsfiddle.net/v43hy5ye/3/ - I want to target settings.divSettings by pulling something more exact from the html if needed.

Comment: Receiving an error on that link + it's not working.  Perhaps wrong link?

Comment: change it to this `settings[$(this).data("setting")][$(this).prop('name')] = value; `

Answer (score 1):

I think you've pretty much got the answer, but I'll show you some things that might help.

Object properties are actually just strings. You can access them with the dot notation when they are valid JavaScript identifiers, or the bracket notation when they get more complex. This means you can just use any constant value from your markup as a point of reference. In your example, two distinct constants are the `name` attributes that group the radio buttons.

Without any changes to your markup, consider this example. You can build off this by figuring out a naming pattern than works for you, which might depend on how you plan to use these values in other sections of your code.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/derojo/1/edit?css,js,console,output)</kbd>

```js
var boolMap = {
  'yes': true,
  'no': false
};

var settings = {};

$('.toggle').change(function () {
  var target = $(this).data('target'),
      name = $(this).attr('name'),
      value = $(this).val();


  if (boolMap[value]) {
    $(target).slideDown(300);
  } else {
    $(target).slideUp(300);
  }
  
  settings[name] = (boolMap[value] ? 1 : 0);
  
  console.log(settings);
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Div 1</p>
<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-one" type="radio" name="enableDivOne" value="yes" checked><span>Yes</span>

<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-one" type="radio" name="enableDivOne" value="no">
<span>No</span>

<p>Div 2</p>
<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-two" type="radio" name="enableDivTwo" value="yes" checked><span>Yes</span>

<input class="toggle" data-target=".div-two" type="radio" name="enableDivTwo" value="no">
<span>No</span>

<div class="div-one">One</div>

<div class="div-two">Two</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```